# How to prevent content jumping/scrolling in Angular 5 with NGRX

Tags: rxjs, angular5, ngrx

Let's say I have a long page with a table (or to be correct with a set of containers that contain tables) and there is a lot of data in these tables, so that it doesn't fit into a screen and therefore it is possible to scroll the page with scrollbars.

Now I have a checkbox in each row of the table so that I can select some rows and perform some actions with them.

These checkboxes are tied to the state so that when I check one of them, the state gets updated and entire page gets re-rendered. If I understand correctly, this leads to unexpected content scrolling (jumping).

So my question is: is there any common approach to avoid this unexpected behavior? I'm thinking of separating user interactions into a separate state, but it feels like a reinventing the wheel a bit. Any other ideas or standard approaches?

Comment: The question is - why do you re-render the page when user ticks a checkbox. If you need to update the data in the table, why not update the values you need to update instead of re-rendering the whole page.

Comment: I don't rerender explicitly. I just update store state (I'm doing that immutable, so that each time user clicks on the checkbox I create a new state in my reducer) and  since I use asyncPipe in my template it get's re-rendered automatically as soon as any changes are detected in the state object.

Comment: Your logic is sound but the browser gets in the way - it will re-render the DOM element cause the ngrx state gets updated & it gets picked by the async pipe. The scrolling occurs, cause the table doesn't fit on screen. You can work around it: don't use async pipe in template, assign table data to component variable inside `.subscribe()` method. Then do update the component table property (mutate the object to prevent whole table re-render) when user ticks the checkbox but do not update ngrx state yet. Only update ngrx table property in `ngOnDestroy()` or when u don't mind re-render

Comment: Actually, I don't think that's a good solution to mutate data outside of store. My checkboxes are used to move table rows between several table components withing one page (main container), so I definitely need to use state for that.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in stackblitz or provide some sample code? I understand the issue but normally this should not cause scrolling. Maybe you have some *ngIf condition that is causing the whole component to be destroyed and recreated?

Comment: @Khalid not sure it is easy replicatable in satckblitz, since it's a bunch of code and components, that interact with the store. I'll try if I have spare time, but in general I think the problem is clear just from my description - since reducers produce new state instance on each call, browser has to rerender new instance on page. So the question is: is there any "standard" approach to resolve that.

Comment: @TopaZ, the issue is not really specific to ngrx, I believe it is more related to creating / destroying components in Angular. Normally, adding components to your screen will not create scrolling, but you may be doing something in your code (e.g. an *ngIf at a higher component level that does not need to be there), and that causes a parent component to be destroyed and recreated. This is what you need to be looking for. Without having some sample code to work with, it's difficult to point that out. I just tried using (setInterval) to add items to a list through ngrx, and no scrolling happened.

Comment: @Khalid of course I have *ngIf and *ngFor on different component levels. If you thing that's the reason, do you have any idea of how to overcome that?

Comment: @TopaZ, Well, it's difficult without the code that is causing the problem. But if I have to give high level hint, it would be: Is there anything that is causing the parent component of your list to be destroyed because of changes in your store (e.g. maybe it gets invalidated and immediately validated, thus causing the scrolling effect? Add logs to ngOnDestroy methods of different components, to see if anything gets killed unexpectedly. Again, I wish to give you a high level answer that solves the problem, but it's very difficult without looking at some code.

Comment: I'm having a really hard time finding good guidance for how to avoid this problem. These kind of issues were the VERY FIRST thing that came to mind when I started learning about NGRX / Observable store patterns. I'm actually using Akita which is similar conceptually and has the same issues. While I can see how to fix certain issues in specific cases (with shareReplay() type hacks) I'm still very concerned about the amount of time it will take to solve all the problems of this nature.

Comment: can you show your component code ?

Comment: @Exterminator I'm still struggling with this myself. Couple things of note : I've noticed that mobile testing mode in Chrome sometimes jumps where a real device wouldn't. This even occurs when the content is in a fixed height DIV. So be sure to test on real devices if mobile is a concern. Also use `trackBy` https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5 to prevent containers being redrawn - or rather being reinitialized if the 'key' is the same. https://medium.com/@ramy_ali/improving-angular-ngfor-performance-through-trackby-ae4cf943b878

Comment: I won't be able to help unless i see the code. I need to see the code and check for the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide the code from my real project because of NDA, so I have to write something similar from scratch. I'll try to do that on weekend if I have some spare time for that.

Comment: You can try to add some kind of placeholder for each element, by doing so it should remove the problem with the jumping scroll. So lets say if you know that you have around `x` elements `y` height, set the height of container that holds the elements from the store to `x*y px`.  If you had completed the demo, please share it with us :)

Comment: You can avoid re-render, don't use async in your html template. You get the data first time when page loads, you need to maintain a local copy of it within your component. When any checkbox is clicked, update the local data and state (store). By doing this, it will be in sync upon every check/uncheck.

Comment: @TopaZ Although I am quite late still - Did you explore trackBy - https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5. It will avoid re-rendering even if the new data is coming from the ngrx store.

Comment: do you emptify list(like `setItems([])`) before requesting most recent data?

Comment: do you have a link / gist to your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Simon_Weaver, @user2216584 your comments were correct: just need to add trackBy to prevent Angular from redrawing containers